# Firewall is active, added port to iptables but still cannot connect

Tags: rhel, iptables, firewall, firewalld, telnet

We have RedHat 8 server. Firewalld is active.
I need to connect to port 5050 from my lap top and from the second server, so I added it to the rules

```
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 5050 -j ACCEPT
service iptables save
```

When trying to connect from second server:

```
telnet 10.244.176.1 5050
Trying 10.244.176.1...
telnet: connect to address 10.244.176.1: No route to host
```

When trying from my lap top `telnet`:

```
Connecting To 10.244.176.1...Could not open connection to the host, on port 5050: Connect failed
```

I can ping that IP from both sources.
Also traceroute output is the following (from the second server level):

```
traceroute 10.244.176.1
traceroute to 10.244.176.1 (10.244.176.1), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  10.244.176.1 (10.244.176.1)  0.287 ms !X  0.293 ms !X  0.286 ms !X
```

What can I do?

Comment: Do you have routes to this IP configured on your second server and your laptop?

Comment: @AlexD I can ping that IP from both sources. And from the server I can see traceroute. Please take a look.
`traceroute 10.244.176.1
traceroute to 10.244.176.1 (10.244.176.1), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  10.244.176.1 (10.244.176.1)  0.287 ms !X  0.293 ms !X  0.286 ms !X`

Comment: @AlexD I added those information above.

Comment: The symbol `!X` in `traceroute` output means "communication administratively prohibited". Your firewall is blocking the communication.

Comment: Check you firewall rules with `iptables -L -v -n`

Comment: @AlexD thank you. Can you conclude maybe something based on the following output? I allowed the port 5050 I do not know what else I need to do?
iptables -L -v -n
`Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 4418K packets, 3463M bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    7   380 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:5050
4418K 3463M LIBVIRT_INP  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using firewalld, why not add the rule to firewalld instead of iptables?

You can list the different zones in your firewalld configuration like this:

`firewall-cmd --get-zones`

If you want to see the rule sets for all zones:

`firewall-cmd --list-all-zones`

If you want to see the rule sets for a specific zone:

`firewall-cmd --zone=$ZONE --list-all` Where $ZONE is the name of one of your zones.

This will allow the port in runtime:

`firewall-cmd --zone=$ZONE --add-port=5050/tcp`

To make the rule permanent:

`firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=$ZONE --add-port=5050/tcp`

So if you wanted to add the rule to just test out first for the public zone:

`firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=5050/tcp`

Then if that works and you wanted to make it permanent:

`firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --add-port=5050/tcp`

Alternatively if you wanted to use a GUI to do this you could launch:

`firewall-config` and do the same thing via a GUI.

Comment: Excellent advice, since firewalld uses the native backend, nftables, which the question seems to miss.